# android source build app can not find android-support-v4.jar

Tags: java, android

I find jar library under here: out/target/product/g32ref/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4_intermediates/javalib.jar

In Settings app,  Android.mk is like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := bouncycastle telephony-common
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := guava android-support-v4 jsr305
ifdef DOLBY_DAP
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += framework_ext
else
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += libsds
endif #DOLBY_DAP

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Settings
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

ifndef DOLBY_DAP
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libsds:ds.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
endif

# Use the folloing include to make our test apk.
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

but, when "mmm -B packages/app/Settings" building it, it will build error. Do you know the android building command where to locale the android-support-v4 jar? and why  can't it find v4-support jar?

```
packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PagerTabStrip
location: package android.support.v4.view
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
                              ^
packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java:889: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PagerTabStrip
location: class com.android.settings.applications.ManageApplications
        PagerTabStrip tabs = (PagerTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ^
packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java:889: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PagerTabStrip
location: class com.android.settings.applications.ManageApplications
        PagerTabStrip tabs = (PagerTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                              ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Settings_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: Leaving directory `/home/lee/develop/tanghui/dhcp_ali'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these following steps

1.May be your Debug Certificate had expired so you just needed to delete ~/.android/debug.keystore and restart Eclipse and everything should work.

2.May be it is looking for jar here :/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/v4/android-support-v4.jar

android-support-v4.jar is found in /extras/android/compatibility/v4

Please make sure you add this as an external jar in the java build path.

Comment: I just remake the android-support-v4 in android source code folder, and every thing goes well. thank you all the same @Ajit Kumar